# Receiving of multiple files using TCP-client

Tags: c#, file, tcp, client

I want to create a TcpClient which automatically gets multiple files from server by their name.

I want to get some ideas how I can build such application.

My idea is:

Make a for loop which contains SwitchCase, where I specify my files names. I really don't know if this will work well.

To go out of for loop I can compare the index operator to numbers of files. If they are equal then I go out of for loop.

**Example of my idea:**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{

switch (----)
        {
            case 'file1':
                code...
                break;
            case 'file2':
                code...
            case 'file3':
                code...
                break;
            case 'file4':
                code...
                break;
            default:
                code...
                break;
        }

}
```

Comment: _From a server_ is not very specific. Which protocol will you be using for communication? Http/ftp/other?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, I will be using FTP or HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like so:

MY app. gets 2 files from server and move files and rename them.

test = mytest
test111 = test2

```
    static string myfile1 = @"C:\inbox\mytest.txt";
    static string myfile2 = @"C:\inbox\test2.txt";
    //files from server        
    static string myServerfile = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\file_client\bin\Debug\test.csv";
    static string myServerfile1 = @"C:\Users\RH-T3\Documents\file_client\bin\Debug\test111.txt";


 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Downloading test.csv");
                        string fileName = "test.csv";
                        Console.WriteLine("Client starts...");
                        //args[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                        file_client client = new file_client(args);
                        Console.WriteLine("efter file_client...");
                        NetworkStream serverStream = client.clientSocket.GetStream();
                        LIB.writeTextTCP(serverStream, fileName);
                        long rest = long.Parse(LIB.readTextTCP(serverStream));

                        byte[] inStream = new byte[rest];

                        while (rest != 0)
                        {
                            rest = rest - serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                            Console.WriteLine("REST: " + rest);

                        }
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,                            FileMode.Create);
                        fs.Write(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                        {
                            fs.Close();
                            serverStream.Close();
                        }
                        if (File.Exists(myfile1))
                        {
                            File.Delete(myfile1);
                        }
                        File.Move(myServerfile, myfile1);

                        Console.WriteLine("Moved");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    } 
                     else  
                       {
                        Console.WriteLine("Downloading .txt file");
                        string fileName = "test111.txt";
                        Console.WriteLine("Client starts...");
                        //args[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                        file_client client = new file_client(args);
                        Console.WriteLine("efter file_client...");
                        NetworkStream serverStream = client.clientSocket.GetStream();
                        LIB.writeTextTCP(serverStream, fileName);
                        long rest = long.Parse(LIB.readTextTCP(serverStream));
                        byte[] inStream = new byte[rest];
                        while (rest != 0)
                        {
             rest = rest - serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                            Console.WriteLine("REST: " + rest);
                        }
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,                            FileMode.Create);
                        fs.Write(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                        {
                            fs.Close();
                            serverStream.Close();
                        }
                        if (File.Exists(myfile2))
                        {
                            File.Delete(myfile2);
                        }
                        File.Move(myServerfile1, myfile2);

                        Console.WriteLine("Moved");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }
        }
                catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot be DONE!");
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

To download a file using ftp you could use the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) and for http use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).
Below is a simple example of how to request a file using http (the method is similar for ftp):

```
public void Download(string url, string localPath)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Create);

    int count;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8096];
    while ((count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 8096)) > 0)
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, count);

    fs.Dispose();
    response.Close();
}
```

Instead of using a switch inside a for loop you should iterate an array:

```
string[] files = new string[]{ url1, url2, ...};
for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    Download(files[i], "file" + i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a very nice answer, very helpful. If you got time can you tell me, what if i use RTSP?

Comment: From what I can tell the [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) is a protocol for controlling media servers, not actual streaming.
Streaming could be handled by the [Real Time Transport Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) for which [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18977/How-to-use-the-managed-RTP-API-classes-in-NET-to-c) might be usefull.
But for transferring files you are better of with ftp or http.